# How can I get the FileVersion information of an executable stored in memory as an array of bytes?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, version

I need to read the `FileVersion` of an executable. The problem is that I don't have an actual file on disk, only an array of bytes.  The FileVersion API only has a `GetVersionInfo(string fileName)` method, it doesn't have any method to grab the version from the file.

I tried looking into the source with a decompiler, but it looks more complicated than what a simple copy/paste can do.

Is there any way to read the `FileVersion` of a file, given that I have the bytes of file contents, without writing the file to disk?

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but have you tried writing your byte array to a file on disc and then calling `GetVersionInfo` on that? (Assuming that the byte array would even contain this information in the first place.)

Comment: Well, you could read the `.rsrc` section from the PE image, but that would probably not be trivial... unless you have a very good reason not to, I'd recommend writing the file to disk.

Comment: Start with http://secana.github.io/PeNet/html/5886c81e-a545-ed37-eb3d-af21b3e00b52.htm

Comment: Taking a peak at the .NET Core [source code for FileVersionInfo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/src/System/Diagnostics/FileVersionInfo.Windows.cs), it looks like just a thin wrapper over Win32. `GetFileVersionInfoEx` requires a file path...so I think you're in a corner with this one. Going to follow this question though, in case you find a workaround!

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton that's one of the constraints that I (probably poorly?) explained in the question. I can't write the file to disk (can't guarantee permissions, no exceptions, etc.)

Comment: @SirRufo I don't see any APIs in that class related to versions. How would I use this to solve my problem?

Comment: @ashes999 did you mange to find a way around this problem?

Comment: @easuter no, unfortunately, I didn't find a way around this. I ended up just writing the file to disk, grabbing the version, and then deleting it. Thanks for the poke -- I'll add a self-accepted answer to this question now.

Comment: @ashes999 thanks for replying. Still hurts my brain that `FileVersion` info has to be extracted from an actual file. Seems like an good problem to tackle as a side-project.

Comment: @easuter you're welcome to try! I looked through the .NET code but couldn't figure out how to do it. As a side project, if solved, it would make a nice NuGet package (or pull request to .NET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after lots of digging, and looking into the .NET Core source, available Javascript libraries, etc. I decided that this is not easy (or at all) possible and not worth the pain to figure out.

Instead, I went with the simpler approach of:

- Write the file to disk in some sort of temporary location
- Read the version from the file on disk
- Delete the file

The code is simple and straight-forward .NET code, no fancy tricks or complicated JS libraries required.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It might be worth noting that my byteArray comes from a .NET assembly that is an embedded resource.

```
Dim assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(byteArray)
Dim currentVersion = assembly.GetName.Version
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using the [`PeNet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeNet) package (as indicated by @SirRufo in the comments above):

```
Public ReadOnly Property FileVersion As Version Implements IBootStrapper.FileVersion
  Get
    Dim oPeFile As PeFile
    Dim aData As Byte()

    If Me.File.Exists Then
      aData = Me.Folders.FileSystem.File.ReadAllBytes(Me.File.FullName)
      oPeFile = New PeFile(aData)

      FileVersion = New Version(oPeFile.Resources.VsVersionInfo.StringFileInfo.StringTable.First.FileVersion)
    Else
      FileVersion = New Version
    End If
  End Get
End Property
```

Getting the `ProductVersion` is another matter entirely. We'll leave that discussion for another day.

For the curious: the `Me.Folders.FileSystem.File` reference is from [`System.IO.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions), for use as a file system mock during testing.